# Area of region of a limaçon

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, area, curves

I have to generalize the concept of finding the region $D$ inside of limaçons without a loop. In particular $r=a+b\cos(\theta)$, where $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, and to prevent the loop $a>b>0$.

My naive approach is to find: $$\int\int_{D}1dxdy = \int_{a-b}^{a+b}\int_{0}^{2\pi}rd\theta dr$$ But then I loose information that $r$ is $a+b\cos\theta$.

I checked how the limaçons with different $a$ and $b$ look like via desmos, but this does not give me any intuition.

Comment: Is that a correct approach to find the area?

Comment: As your bounds are you're just integrating on the area between two circles. You should rethink your bounds for $r.$

Comment: For any $\theta ,$ your $r$ will be between $0$ and $a + b\cos\theta ,$ given that $a > b > 0.$

Comment: So correct version should be $\int_{0}^{a+b\cos\theta} (*) dr$ and the rest remains

Comment: Not quite, you have to have the $\theta$s inside of the $\theta$ integral. So switch the order to $drd\theta.$

Comment: I meant $\int_{0}^{a+b\cos\theta} (\int_{0}^{2\pi} r d\theta) dr$. Order does not matter but first I integrate w.r.t. to $\theta$, where it goes between $0$ and $2\pi$ and then for $r$, which is $0<r<a+b\cos\theta$.

Comment: That's the problem, because your bounds are variable, the order does matter. Notice that in the order you have now, you're going to get an answer in terms of $\theta,$ which is nonsensical.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did not realize that. That was very helpful. Thus my final version is $\int_{0}^{2\pi}  (\int_{0}^{a+b\cos\theta} r dr) d\theta$.

Comment: That should work, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By analogy to the rectangular integral to find the area of $\int y\; dx$ the usual way to find the area in polar coordinates is $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac 12r^2\; d\theta$.  The area element is approximately a triangle with height $r$ and base $r\; d\theta$, so area $\frac 12 r^2 d\theta$.  Now you substitute in your formula for $r$ to get $\frac 12\int_0^{2\pi} (a+b\cos \theta)^2\; d\theta$.  A good picture is [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/PolarArea.aspx).

Comment: I see that this comes from $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{r} r dr d\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r^2}{2} d\theta = \cdots$. And I just finally need to substitute $r$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

An example, symmetric to x-axis.

$$r= 3+2 \cos \theta, Area= 2\int _0^\pi \frac12 r^2 d \theta $$

Answer (score 0):

I approached this from the complex plane, where the area is given by

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int \Im\{z^*\dot z\}\ d\theta$$

Then,

$$
z=re^{i\theta}\\
z*=re{-i\theta}\\
\dot z=(ir+\dot r)e^{i\theta}\\
\Im\{z^*\dot z\}=r^2
$$

And finally

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(a+b\cos\theta)^2\ d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\pi(2a^2+b^2)
$$

According to *A Catalog of Special Plane Curves* by J. Denus Lawrence, Dover Press. 1972, this is the total area for a single or double loop limaçon.